# Set Maximum Memory Usage?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on creating some super basic virtual machine software. I have just started working on the project. Essentially what I have in mind is creating a folder with a / file system inside, and a certain amount of RAM allocated to the process (set by the user). Is there a way to set how much RAM a python script (or, for that matter, a thread specifically) is allowed to use?
I have done some research but no other questions answer how to specifically set the value before hand...they mostly deal with `MemoryError` errors. 
Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to happen when it reaches that limit?

Comment: @bytesized force other processes (that are running on that thread) to wait. just sort of like partitioning the RAM if you will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running on Linux or some other Unix-like OS, try ulimit (`man ulimit`) and the coresponding Python module `resource`.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can use the [`SetProcessWorkingSetSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686234%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)`(Ex)` function.